# SELECT Dropdown that redirects without Javascript

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to create a  dropdown that redirects the user when he selects an option without javascript?

When the user selects a category in dropdown A, I display dropdown B (which has subcategories) with Javascript. I want to make it work similarly for users without Javascript. My idea is to redirect users to different pages when they choose an option in the first dropdown.

Is this possible without javascript? How can it be done? (if not if possible suggest something)

Comment: You'll need Javascript for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The most minimalistic solution is using inline JS in the HTML.

---

Note: which kind of browser do you want to support? Even IE7 has the JS support you need.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't work in IE versiones older than IE8 while in fact does. But still I would like it to work with .js disabled. Don't know how common it is though but the more compatible the better.

Comment: You can assume that every browser has JS. The few that don't have an owner that can't think clearly, and those are not you problem. With this simple JS you are even safe concerning companies with old computers.

Comment: Some people choose to turn off javaScript. Other disabled users may rely on a non-traditional user agent such as an aural or Braille reader which may not support javaScript. My company is very strong on DDA compliance and we have a corporate policy to write code that works on a braindead user agent without JavaScript, and then progressively enhance the code to look decent on a sane browser. Having said that, there's no way to do what the OP wants without using javaScript.

Comment: If you choose to turn off JS you don't deserve getting any any nice functionalities. I understand that there are user policies, but look at all the major websites, and imagine all of them working without JS. Quite impossible.

Answer (score 2):

While admittedly not elegant, I've come to this solution;

```
<form action="/" method="GET">
    <select name="path">
        <option value="home">Home</option>
        <option value="services">Our services</option>
        <option value="portfolio">Portfolio</option>
    </select>

    <input id="fallback-go" type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Selecting ```Our Services`'' then clicking `Go` would result in them being sent to `/?path=services`

Unfortunately, I can't fathom a way to do it automatically on select change, I'll post a reply if I do.

In order to hide the `Go` button from users with JavaScript support, this could be implemented;

```
<head>
    <style>
        #fallback-go { display: none; }
        .no-script #fallback-go { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="no-script">
    <script>document.body.classname = '';</script>

    [ other HTML ]
</body>
```

As for your double-layered dropdown menu; this is possible using a pure CSS solution. The problem with a pure CSS solution is it wouldn't play nicely with IE7, due to it's lack of pseudo-element support.

If you want all-around support, I'd recommend to implement the JavaScript solution to keep IE7 up-to-par, and a pure CSS solution to keep noscript happy.

As a noscript user, I appreciate your efforts greatly.