# Redirect with HTML dropdown select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML drop-down select box.

**I would like this to function as 'once something is selected' > the page then redirects to a custom URL.**

*Below is my mark-up.*

```
<fieldset id="size"><legend>Product Options</legend>
<div class="wpsc_variation_forms">
<table>
<tr><td class="col1"><label for="variation_select_48_5">Choose Size:</label></td>
<td class="col2"><select class="wpsc_select_variation" name="variation[5]" id="variation_select_48_5">
<option value="0" >-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="8" >Large</option>
<option value="7" >Medium</option>
<option value="6" >Small</option>
</select></td></tr>
</table>
</div><!--close wpsc_variation_forms-->
</fieldset>
```

I found a similar question; but the solution given seems a bit clunky.

[SELECT Dropdown that redirects without Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967182/select-dropdown-that-redirects-without-javascript)

Comment: where does the custom url come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#variation_select_48_5').change(function() {
        document.location = 'http://customurl.abc';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i know of is assigning an `onchange` event to select element and making options' values as urls.

```
<select onchange="window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="http://your-url">Large</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write i litte function and then trigger it depending on the retuned result

```
<?PHP
    function redirect($where){      
       header("Location: $where");
    }

    if ($_REQUEST['select1'] == '8'){
        redirect('http://example.com/somewhere.php');
    }elseif($_REQUEST['select1'] == '7'){
        redirect('http://example.com/elsewhere.php');
    }elseif($_REQUEST['select1'] == '6'){
        redirect('http://example.com/elsewhere.php');
    }
?>

<form>
<select name="select1" class="wpsc_select_variation" name="variation[5]" id="variation_select_48_5" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="0" >-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="8" >Large</option>
<option value="7" >Medium</option>
<option value="6" >Small</option>
</select>
```

the only javascript required is within the `select` tag to trigger the submit `onchange="this.form.submit()"`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$("select#wpsc_select_variation").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() !== 0) {
        switch($(this).val())
        { 
            case(8):
                window.location.href = http://www.8.com
            case(7):
                window.location.href = http://www.7.com
            case(6):
                window.location.href = http://www.6.com
        }
    }
});
```