# Make a "href" list menu with only html and css

Tags: html, list, select, hyperlink, href

Here is my code :

```
    <li class="bouton_produit">
        <select>
            <option> Produit </option>
            <option> <a href="ajouter_produit.php">Ajouter un Produit Semi Fini</a> </option>
            <option> <a href="ajouter_produit_final.php">Ajouter un Produit Fini</a> </option>
        </select>
    </li>
```

What i'm trying to do is when i click on "Ajouter un Produit Semi Fini", it send me on the page ""ajouter_produit.php" and when i click on "Ajouter un Produit Fini" it sends me on the page "ajouter_produit_final.php".

My problem, i have the list but when i click, it "choose" me only the link, its not like a real href link when it sends me on another page.

Soo how can i do this  using only HTML and CSS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a>` tag has no effect in `select` options. You should use the `onchange` event in JavaScript.

In fact the question is a duplicate of [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)

Also the following question already asked: [SELECT Dropdown that redirects without Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967182/select-dropdown-that-redirects-without-javascript) has a negative answer to the question of whether this can be done without javascript.

Comment: Is it possible with just HTML and CSS ? I don't want to use JavaScript (i never used)

Comment: This is another question -- I recommend you to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Technically yes. You could create a CSS dropdown menu where you place these links instead of using select. See this: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

since `a` doesnot work inside option as it is supposed to, you can take href link value inside `option` as value and take it with jquery and set it to window.location.href.

if you never used js before, now it is time to learn js. it is never bad to know it ;)

```
<li class="bouton_produit">
 <select id="selected">
    <option>Produit</option>
    <option value="ajouter_produit.php">Ajouter un Produit Semi Fini</option>
    <option value="ajouter_produit_final.php">Ajouter un Produit Fini</option>
 </select>
</li>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
 $('#selected').on('change',function(){
  var href_link = $(this).val();
  window.location.href = href_link;
 });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3xY7L/

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes. You could create a CSS dropdown menu where you place these links instead of using select. See this: line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: LoL did you just copy the answer of Ahmet Özışık Oo